# vuex-class: accessing Vuex outside of a Vue component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

How can I get access to Vuex outside of a Vue component with vuex-class?

In normal situation it is pretty simple:

```
// some JS file
import store from './../store'; // path to Vuex store

store.commit('ux/mutationName', somePayload)
```

But I am using vuex-class and I have Vuex module:

```
import { Module } from 'vuex';
import { RootState } from '@/types/vuex/types';
import { MutationTree } from 'vuex';
import { GetterTree } from 'vuex';

const namespaced: boolean = true;

export interface UXState {
  compLoading: boolean;
}

export const state: UXState = {
  compLoading: false
};

export const mutations: MutationTree<UXState> = {
  setCompLoading(state, payload: boolean): void {
    state.compLoading = payload;
  }
};

export const getters: GetterTree<UXState, RootState> = {
  compLoading(state): boolean {
    return state.compLoading;
  }
};

export const ux: Module<UXState, RootState> = {
  namespaced,
  state,
  mutations,
  getters
};
```

Fom Vue component I have access to store Mutations in this way:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import axios from 'axios';
  import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import {Mutation} from "vuex-class";
  const namespace: string = "ux";

  @Component({
    name: 'CompName'
  })
  export default class AppNavigationBar extends Vue {

    @Mutation('setCompLoading', { namespace })
    setCompLoading!: (flag: boolean) => void;

    async created() {
      this.setCompLoading(true);
      const resp = await axios.get('someURL');
      this.setCompLoading(false);
    }
  }
</script>
```

How can I get access to Mutation using vuex-class with TS outside of a Vue component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you are using vuex-class, you can still use mutations the old way:

```
import store from './../store';

store.commit('module/mutationName', payload);
```

Or, if you prefer to use the typed mutation directly:

```
import state from './../store/state';
import { MUTATION_NAME } from  './../store/mutations'; // Or wherever you have them

MUTATION_NAME(state, payload);
```